# REST Response file to String

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

```
URL url = new URL(binpath);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
String mt = connection.getContentType();
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) is, mt);
response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + binpath.substring(binpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, binpath.length()));
return response.build();
```

I have a REST service with the above code (`Response`). When called saves a file with text values like "file1 addsagfdfgfd"

When I call this from another class and use the `Response` to get the content as follows, it is not giving me the content of the response. It returns

```
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseImpl@66e5a761
String rp = file1Response.toEntity().toString();
```

How can I get the string value from the rest Response (which is a file) or how can I change the code to return a string?

Comment: Could you please post the entire method?

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the file to a `String` or make an own class containing all information about the file and its content. You probably have an issue with the `MessageBodyWriter`.

If you transform your file to a String you can easily put it in the response body. Same applies for a self written class. You can control which fields will be sent with the body by annotating the fields you don't want to sent with `@XmlTransient`.

I guess that the `MessageBodyWriter` cant handle the `InputStream`. Have you ever checked the HTTP status code? It will probably be `500 Internal Server Error` and in your logs you should see something like "MessageBodyWriter not found for type InputStream".

Also you should write the whole method code in your questions providing all variables that you use inside that method.